# Inserting a tab or space between specific characters based on character and character length

Tags: c#

I need to insert a tab between numbers and letters:

*Example Input:* `44World Cup` *Output:* `44 World Cup`
The problem I am having is, I also need to specify the length of the words next to the number.

For example: I do not want to insert a space if the word is `th` or `TH`, or if the letters or words next to the number is equals 2 in length.

Example: I live on `44th Avenue` will not be affected, however, I live of 44Avenue will be changed to. I live on `44 Avenue`.

So far all I have is this regex, close but not very effective:

```
public string AddSpace(string input)
{
 return Regex.Replace(input, 
"(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])", " ");
}
```

The code above inserts a tab between any number letters/words sequence.

Comment: You can add `{3,}` to your regex as follows: `(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z]{3,})|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])`

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution for your problem. Since there is many situations in which you going to have letters and numbers together for example "1st" , "2nd" , "3rd" and many others.

The only way is to look for each and every case and threat it as one word.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Dictionary<int,string>` object to map digits with allowed suffixes. For example, (1,"st"), (2,"nd"), (3,"rd") etc.

Now, whenever you encounter a group of digits in your string, take the last digit and the first two characters after that digit, and check against the dictionary to determine of a space/tab should be inserted or not.

This is a complex logic and cannot be done via regex, in my opinion.